# Finding doubles in an int

Tags: python

If I have the integer, 1988, how could iterate thru it to see if there are doubles? In python.

I know I can't just iterate thru it like this:

```
userInt = 1988
for i in userInt:
    print(i)
```

Comment: What do you mean by seeing if there are doubles? Your code right now will raise an error because you can't iterate through an integer.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert it to a string:

```
userInt = 1988
for i in str(userInt):
    print(i)
```

If you want to see if there are any doubles, do this:

```
has_doubles = len(set(str(userInt))) == len(str(userInt))
```

Comment: Thank you. i don't know how I count think about that

Comment: If my answer helped you, please consider marking it as the correct answer by clicking the grey check mark below the vote-count.

Answer (score 1):

If the following test cases are correct:

```
tests = {1: False, 
         11: True, 
         00: False, 
         12344: True, 
         1202: False, 
         9999: True, 
         1234: False, }
```

Then, the following should work:

```
def has_doubles(val):
    as_string = str(val)
    if len(as_string) < 2:
        return False
    for x in range(len(as_string) - 1):
        if as_string[x] == as_string[x+1]:
            return True
    return False
```

Note that 1202 does not have a "double", if it does, then the other answer should work.  Also, the length check at the beginning is not strictly needed as range(0) is empty, but no harm in being explicit. The for loop just looks at adjacent characters and tests for equality.